# What is a geometric demonstration of the harmonic and geometric means in Archimedes' approximation of π?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, math-history, pi

Going through Archimedes' approximation to π using the method of inscribed and circumscribed polygons, one comes upon his recursive formulae for their perimeters. Representing the perimeter of the circumscribed and inscribed polygons with $n$ sides as $P_n$ and $p_n$, respectively, the recursion is:
$$
P_{2n} = \dfrac{2 p_n P_n}{p_n + P_n} \qquad
p_{2n} = \sqrt{p_n P_{2n}}
$$
It is relatively straightforward to prove these by algebraic manipulation of the double angle formulae into the following forms:
$$
\tan\alpha = \frac{\tan{2\alpha} \sin{2\alpha}}{\tan{2\alpha} + \sin{2\alpha}}  \qquad
\sin\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sqrt{\tan\alpha \sin{2\alpha}}
$$
However, each of these formulae is a statement about means of certain quantities:

- $P_{2n}$ is the harmonic mean of $p_n$ and $P_n$.
- $\tan\alpha$ is half the harmonic mean of $\tan{2\alpha}$ and $\sin{2\alpha}$.
- $p_{2n}$ is the geometric mean of $p_n$ and $P_{2n}$.
- $\sin\alpha$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ times the geometric mean of $\tan\alpha$ and $\sin{2\alpha}$.

Given that geometric reasoning was much more important is Archimedes' time – and algebraic manipulation much more rudimentary – I suspect there's a geometric way of directly seeing these facts, and this is how Archimedes would have proven these formulae. What is a diagram we could draw which would make this clear? In particular, is there a diagram which would make the appearance of the geometric and harmonic means seem natural, for example through an application of the [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem) or one of the many appearances of the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#In_geometry).

*Aside:* there is a very similar recursive formula for the areas of the circumscribed and inscribed polygons:
$$
A_{2n} = \dfrac{2 a_{2n} A_n}{a_{2n} + A_n} \qquad
a_{2n} = \sqrt{a_n A_n}
$$
I imagine that a diagram demonstrating the formulae for the perimeter would be fairly easily adapted to show those for the areas, but if it's more convenient you are welcome to demonstrate this one instead.

Comment: Assume that you are using *regular* polygons, where each side is of equal length.  Let $n$ be the number of sides of both the inscribed and circumscribed polygons, and let their areas be $A$ and $B$ respectively.  Let the area of the corresponding circle be $C$.  My **blind guess**, which could easily be wrong, is that Archimedes simply observed that with $A < C < B$, as $n \to \infty,$ $A \to C$ and $B \to C$.  That is, he observed that the area between the circle and each of the two polygons decreased, as $n$ increased.

Comment: My further understanding, which could also be wrong is that he assumed (accurately, but perhaps invalidly) that as $n\to \infty$ both $|A-C|$ and $|B-C|$ went $\to 0$.

Comment: @user2661923: Yes, we are using regular polygons. I'll note that Archimedes used perimeters rather than areas, but that's beside the point.
Archimedes did much more than just observing that the error went to 0 in the limit: he provided a recursive formula to actually calculate the perimeters of the circumscribed/inscribed polygons with twice as many sides. It's this more specific fact that I'm asking about.

Comment: Interesting, good clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $Q_n := \frac{1}{2n}P_n$ and $q_n := \frac{1}{2n}p_n$ as the half-sides of circumscribed and inscribed $n$-gons. We'll demonstrate the target relation translated to these values:
$$Q_{2n}=\frac{Q_n q_n}{Q_n+q_n} \qquad\qquad 2q_{2n}^2= Q_n q_n \tag{1}$$

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be consecutive vertices of the circumscribed $n$-gon; then midpoints $M$ and $N$ of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$ (the points of tangency with the circle) are consecutive vertices on the inscribed $n$-gon; thus, $|BM|=|BN|=Q_n$. Let $L$ be the midpoint of $\overline{MN}$, so that $|ML|=|NL|=q_n$. Let $D$ be the point where $\overline{BL}$ meets the circle, $E$ be the point where the tangent at $D$ meets $\overline{BN}$, and $F$ be the midpoint of $DN$ (necessarily the altitude of $\triangle DEN$), so that $|DN|=Q_{2n}$ and $|DF|=q_{2n}$.

[image]

For the $Q_{2n}$ relation, first observe that $\angle NMD$ and $\angle BMD$ are inscribed angles (the latter being somewhat *honorarily* "inscribed" as the angle between a tangent and a chord) subtending congruent arcs $\overset{\frown}{MD}$ and $\overset{\frown}{DN}$, so that they themselves are congruent (by the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem)); therefore, $\overline{MD}$ bisects $\angle BMN$, and so it cuts $\overline{BL}$ in proportion $|MB|:|ML|$ (by the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)). Also, $\overline{DE}\parallel \overline{LN}$, so that $\triangle BDE\sim \triangle BLN$. From these facts, we can write
$$\frac{|DE|}{|LN|} = \frac{|BD|}{|BD|+|DL|} = \frac{|MB|}{|MB|+|ML|} \quad\to\quad \frac{Q_{2n}}{q_n}=\frac{Q_n}{Q_n+q_n} \tag{2}$$
For the $q_{2n}$ relation, simply observe that $\triangle NDL \sim \triangle DEF$, giving
$$\frac{|ND|}{|NL|}=\frac{|DE|}{|DF|} \quad\to\quad \frac{2q_{2n}}{q_n}=\frac{Q_{2n}}{q_{2n}} \tag{3}$$
Clearly, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equivalent to $(1)$. $\square$

For now, I'll leave the area results as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. It may be obvious to others, but I had to do a bit more to convince myself that MD bisects the angle BMN. It may be worth adding a couple of words citing the inscribed angle theorem and the ‘angle between a chord and a tangent’ theorem.

Comment: @StephenMorgan: Edited! :)

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it does exactly what I asked: provides a diagram which justifies the recursive formulae. However, I still feel that there's a bit of mystery, as the harmonic and geometric means just kind of fall out of things. These have geometric meaning in many cases (e.g. [the crossed ladder problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_ladders_problem) and [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem)), and it would be nice to see a solution which makes this explicit.

Comment: @StephenMorgan: There may well be approaches that make the mean connections less mysterious. (I'm still pondering them. :)  ... It's perfectly okay to refrain from accepting an answer (especially the first one) if you think a more-satisfying one may be lurking out there. Indeed, such a case, it's better *not* to accept an answer right away, as the checkmark may serve to tell other ostensible answerers not to bother. (Generally, I recommend waiting a couple of days, to give people time to roll the problem around in their heads.) Feel free to uncheck me ... for now. ;)

Comment: @StephenMorgan: BTW, comments (especially comments on someone's answer) are easily overlooked, and may be hidden, so you should [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4175219/edit) to state *there* what you're seeking from an ideal solution. This will help people avoid spending time posting solutions that, like mine, may have a bit too much mystery to them.